# How to change react component through select option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to change a component, based on Dropdown value? Is it possible without router?
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cherry-2qcwx?file=/src/App.js
on state change by select dropdown  I need to switch the headers   ,
, . Please help, Thanks in advance

```
    <div className="container">
    <header>
    <HeadertypeA />
    <HeadertypeB />
    <HeadertypeC />
    </header>
    <section>Page Body</section>
    <footer>footer </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object mapping select values to component:

```js
const headerTypeObject = {
  "a": HeaderTypeA,
  "b": HeaderTypeB,
  "c": HeaderTypeC
}
```

You also need a state variable to keep track:

```js
const [currentHeaderType, setCurrrentHeaderType] = React.useState("a");
```

Then you can render:

```
<div>
<select value = {currentHeaderType} onChange = {e => setCurrentHeaderType(e.target.value)}>
  {Object.keys(headerTypeObject).map((type, i) => (
    <option key = {i} value = {type}> {type} </option>
  ))}
</select>
{headerTypeObject[currentHeaderType]() /* This is the header component we will render*/}
</div>
```